# Convert dict to class dynamically in python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary, casting

I know similar questions have been previously answered, but after spending hours browsing the web, I still cannot the right solution to my problem (or the 'python-way' solution)

I'm using the following 'database' module to insert any object into MongoDB:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

def insert(obj, collection_name):
    with MongoClient(27017, 'localhost') as client:
        if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'):
            doc = obj.__dict__
        else:
            doc = json.dumps(obj)
        return client['test'][collection_name].insert_one(doc).inserted_id

def get_one(collection_name, query):
    with MongoClient(27017, 'localhost') as client:
        return client['test'][collection_name].find_one(query)
```

This part works well as I can handle any class in any module and store the objects in a generic way.

The issue I'm facing is to reload an object from MongoDB and cast it back to the correct class.

I have a generic class 'Operation' (representing an action that can be done to bank/money account:

```
import database 

class Operation(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = 'OPE-{}'.format(str(uuid.uuid1()))

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id

    def save(self):
        database.update(self, 'operations')

def create_from_dict(d):
    operation = Operation()
    for key, value in d.items():
        operation.__dict__[key] = value
    return operation

def get(operation_id):
    return create_from_dict(database.get_one('operations', {'_id': operation_id}))
```

Until this point everything works, I can instantiate any Operation object, insert it into MongoDB and load it back using it's id.

Now I have two new classes 'Fee' and 'Credit' derived from 'Operation'

```
import uuid
from operation import Operation

class Credit(Operation):
    def __init__(self):
        Operation.__init__(self)
        self._id = 'CRE-{}'.format(uuid.uuid1())

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id
```

And

```
import uuid
from operation import Operation

class Fee(Operation):
    def __init__(self):
        Operation.__init__(self)
        self._id = 'FEE-{}'.format(uuid.uuid1())

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id
```

The idea is to have keep the code to save/load objects in the 'Operation' class and create simple derived class whenever needed.
So the 'Operation' class should be able to cast dynamically the loaded object from Operation to Credit/Fee/Transfer...

What I tried to do is add the following line on all classes in order to store the object type:

```
self.type = self.__class__
```

Or alternatively (since the class cannot be directly serialized to json)

```
self.type = self.__name__
```

But I don't know how I could achieve the :

```
def create_from_dict(d):
    operation = Operation()
    for key, value in d.items():
        operation.__dict__[key] = value
    operation.__class__ = get_type_from_name(operation.type) #This is the function I'm trying to implement
    return operation
```

Should I store both the module and the class name when encoding the object to cast it back from another module?

Sorry for the quite long question but I wanted to fully describe the logic behind my code
I'm definitely quite open at any suggestion!

EDIT:
Could locals() or globals() be the way to go? You pass the class name to the get_type_from_name() method and it returns the corresponding class?
Additional question for advanded Pythonists: is that the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `self.type = self.__name__` idea you suggested, you could try this implementation for the `get_type_from_name` function:

```
def get_type_from_name(name):
    name_to_type = {'Credit': Credit, 'Fee':Fee}
    return name_to_type[name]
```

I'm not quite sure that I fully understand your problem though, so let me know if this isn't what you want.

Comment: This is the idea but I'd rather not have to maintain a static mapping Name/Class. And since the derived classed (Credit, Fee) have a dependency on Operation I'm trying to avoid any circular dependencies. What I was thinking is a method inside Operation that would cast objects without any reference to the objects classes. Does this make sense?

Comment: It does appear that `locals()` contains the information you want, so it may just be possible to do `return locals()[name]` and be done with it, although that's starting to get into some pretty hacky territory, and you may want to figure out if there isn't a better way to do what you're trying to do. For example, the most robust solution would be to pickle each object, and then shove that into a binary field in MongoDB. Or at the very least, you could pickle the class itself, and store that (so that you don't need to dynamically recreate it yourself from a string).

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to make it work:

Adding this to the classes I want to (de)serialize:

```
self.type = self.__class__.__name__
self.module = self.__module__
```

Then once the json doc is loaded from PyMongo:

```
    if not hasattr(doc, 'module') or not hasattr(doc, 'type'):
        return obj
    for key, value in doc.items():
        obj.__dict__[key] = value
    mod = __import__(obj.module, fromlist=[obj.type])
    obj.__class__ = getattr(mod, obj.type)
```

The last two lines import the module containing the class and modify the object **class** dynamically.

Thanks user3030010 for your answer.
But I'm still very curious to know if you guys think this a good design or that could lead to more issues.